# java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity component info (Android)

Tags: android

I am getting the following exception in my android code but i can't figure it out. I have extended my Home activity with `TabActivity` and receiving intents in it from `MainActivity`. In the tab3 i have passed intents to another activity which will start on selecting the tab3. The data from the intent is being received in that activity. I have checked it by Log. This received data will be shown in `ListView` of that activity. But unfortunately my app breaks down. Any help regarding this? 
Here is my logcat.

```
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): Process: com.example.app, PID: 1147
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Home1}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.CameraList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.CameraList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2019)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.app.Home1.setNewTab(Home1.java:136)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.app.Home1.onCreate(Home1.java:83)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     ... 11 more
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.app.CameraList.onCreate(CameraList.java:40)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     ... 22 more
```

And this is the place where i used tabs in Home activity..

```
String [] names;
names = intent.getStringArrayExtra("name");
    if(tag.equals("tab3"))
    {
        Intent ListIntent = new Intent(this, List.class);
        ListIntent.putExtra("itemName", names);
        tabSpec.setContent(ListIntent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
```

The activity where I recieve the intent in the OnCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cam_list);

    //Log.i("cam","List");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringArrayExtra("camName");
    //Log.i("cam", name[1]);
    url = intent.getStringArrayExtra("url");

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.cam_list,R.id.text1, name);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    /*list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

              // ListView Clicked item value
              String  itemValue    = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
              String camUrl = url[position];

               // Show Alert 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),camUrl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    });*/
}
```

Comment: What is line 40 in `CameraList.java`?

Comment: can you show ur total oncreate?

Comment: i have shown it..plz check it.
@CommonsWare at line40.. i am setting the adapter.

Comment: @RabiaMehmood : All activities registered in your `manifest` ?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 14:36:34.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.app.CameraList.onCreate(CameraList.java:40)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes @LancePreston..All activities are registered there.

Comment: @RabiaMehmood : What does your `MainActivity` extend ?

Comment: @LancePreston my MainActivity is extending Activity. From there i am starting Home activity which is extending TabActivity. And from TabActivity the third activity is being called in which i m showing the listView.

Comment: "at line40.. i am setting the adapter" -- if you mean `list.setAdapter(adapter)`, then perhaps you are not calling `setContentView()` or otherwise causing this `ListView` to exist.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. There was a mistake in my setContentView().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a `NullPointerException` on a `View` you retrieved from `findViewById()`, Android is telling you that the `View` does not exist. There are two main possibilities here:

1. The `View` really does not exist, such as failing to call `setContentView()` when you needed to.
2. If you are using Eclipse, sometimes the `R` constants get out of sync with the contents of your APK file. To fix this, choose Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu, then try running your app again. Fortunately, I have not seen this behavior with Android Studio (thank `$DEITY` for small favors...).